# Objective C launchApplicationAtUrl arguments not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsworkspace

I would like to open Photoshop app with some arguments via launchApplicationAtURL. Photoshop is opened but the image that I specified in the parameter list is not opened.

```
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:imageEditorPath.GetPlatformString().c_str()];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:urlString];
//Handle url==nil
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *arguments = [NSArray     arrayWithObjects:@"/Users/admin/q/177381.png", nil];
[workspace launchApplicationAtURL:url options:0 configuration: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:arguments forKey:NSWorkspaceLaunchConfigurationArguments] error:&error];
```

Comment: imageEditorPath.GetPlatformString().c_str()  = "/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019.app"  - it working nice

Comment: You can just do this: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Users/admin/q/177381.png" withApplication:@"Adobe Photoshop CC 2019"];`

Comment: Thank you CJK. 

The example above is very simplified.
Problem is current NSArray example contain only one argument but i have to fiil it dynamically from a vector which can contain 2 or more path for images.

Comment: In that case, you can use `openURLs:withApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:`, passing `0` for `options:` and `configuration:` to use standard defaults.

Comment: [workspace launchApplicationAtURL:url options:0 configuration:0 error:&error];

Ok, but if configuration:0 how can get function arguments NSArray??

Comment: `[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:fileURLs withApplicationAtURL:appURL options:0 configuration:0 error:&err];` where `fileURLs` is your array of files to be opened, and `appURL` points to the application.

Comment: I tested it but it didn't work.   <br/>
I checked with debugger appUrl = "file:///Applications/Adobe%20Photoshop%20CC%202019/Adobe%20Photoshop%20CC%202019.app"  -- it's OK.   <br/>
From terminal command line: open file:///Applications/Adobe%20Photoshop%20CC%202019/Adobe%20Photoshop%20CC%202019.app  -- Photoshop opened it's OK.  <br/>  <br/>

appURL - do nothing Photoshop not opened (for safety's sake I set openURLs to 0)  <br/>
`[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:0 withApplicationAtURL:appURL options:0 configuration:0 error:&err];`

Comment: If I change code ... with same appURL does work and open Photoshop
NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
`[workspace launchApplicationAtURL:appURL options:0 configuration:0 error:&err];`  <br/>  

Strange

Comment: It works now. I found two problems. 1. openUrls NSArray has NSString members so I converted them to NSURL  2. I have to use fileURLWithPath for NSString -> NSURL conversion.  Thank you for your patience. It was a good job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing my comments above, one can open multiple files in an application using the `NSWorkspace` method [**`openURLs:withApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error:`**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1528548-openurls?language=objc).  If you don't need to send any arguments to the application, or set environment variables for the app, then one can simply pass `NULL` to the `configuration:` parameter.  Likewise, there are [a multitude of `NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions` available](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspacelaunchoptions?language=objc), but if none of those are desired, one can pass `0` to the `options:` parameter:

```
NSURL *appURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file:///path/to/application.app"];
NSArray *fileURLs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file:///path/to/file1"],
                                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file:///path/to/file2"],
                                              nil];
NSError *err = nil;
BOOL success = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:fileURLs withApplicationAtURL:appURL 
                                              options:0 configuration:NULL error:&err];
```

Answer (score 0):

CJKs answer is right:
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURLs:fileURLs withApplicationAtURL:appURL options:0 configuration:0 error:&err]; where fileURLs is your array of files to be opened, and appURL points to the application. – CJK

CJK - Please send it as answer.